# When to say selichot in a minyan that doesn't

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, yom-kippur, selichot

Note: This question is practical, however, my rav is not capable of answering it from his own experience, due to the nature of mainstream Orthodox kehillot in the US.

According to Western Ashkenazi practice, we say selichot during all services of Yom Kippur. However, in my area, this is not the practice and most actually only say them during Ma'ariv, Musaf, and Ne'ilah. At what point should one say selichot during the chazzan's repetition in a minyan which does not say them?

Comment: I would bounty this, but I can't until after Y"K (:

Comment: "At what point should one say": I'd think "Should one say, and at what point should one say," would be a better question.

Comment: If your rav can't answer it, I'd recommend asking another rav. Any real rabbi is better than this site, if your looking for a practical answer.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt The fact that they say selichos at musaph is amazing. Most shuls don't

Comment: @JoshuaPearl, they're not the real selichos w/ י"ג מדות, just the piyutei selichos and שמע קולני. Gut Jontiv